# Problem to build docker image with Oracle instantclient in amd64 architecture MAC m1 m2

Tags: oracle, docker, macos, x86-64

I know that Oracle Instant Client is not yet compatible with the MAC amd64 architecture, but perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction.

I am attempting to rebuild a Docker image that uses oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.4.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm.

The last time I ran the command
`docker build -t us.icr.io/mynamespace/myimage:version .`
it was executed on an x86 architecture MAC. Now that I have updated to an M1, I am encountering the following error:

```
4.925 oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.4.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm is for architecture amd64 ; the package cannot be built on this system
------
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  23 |     RUN wget https://...theurltotherpmrepo.../oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.4.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
  24 |     RUN apt install alien libaio1 -y
  25 | >>> RUN alien -i oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.4.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
  26 |     RUN sh -c 'echo /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf'
  27 |     RUN ldconfig
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c alien -i oracle-instantclient-basiclite-21.4.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

I've tried it with Rosetta, but I'm getting the same error.

The only solution I can think of right now is to move the build process to the cloud.
Is there any workaround, or another way to install the Oracle Instant Client without using alien?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't get code for x86 to compile on M1. It is literally written for different hardware architecture on the most basic level. You can try the ARM (aarch64) client (the M1 is based on ARM), but no guarantees that will work either. Oracle hasn't certified any of their software on that hardware architecture yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the specifics of installing an rpm file but generally speaking it all depends on what architecture your docker host and the container has.
I assume you want to install the Oracle instant client in a container running linux for the arm architecture. Docker itself runs on macOS using Apple Silicon. In this configuration you would need to use the OIC for ARM architecture in your Linux ARM container. Please also note that you can just download a zip file with all the needed OIC files and just extract and copy them.

Comment: and latest time I looked on ORACLE site, the native ARM version for Linux of the OIC was a 19-serie  not a 21.